# Anti-spam filtering in Exchange 2016 vs Office 365

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

Is there a difference in capability in spam filtering between Exchange 2016 on-prem and Office 365?  I'm evaluating upgrading our on-prem Exchange server or moving to the cloud, and I don't know if improved anti-spam / anti-malware filtering is better or worse with either option.

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely a difference.  A "normal" Office 365 setup will change your MX record to `domain.mail.protection.outlook.com`.  They do lots of things using Exchange Online Protection before a message even hits Transport.

[This talk from Ignite 2015](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK3161) goes deep into EOP and how they work.

With only Exchange 2016, you're pretty much limited to what you can do with transport rules and some canned policies.  [Technet Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150481(v=exchg.160).aspx).  Long story short, If you keep your MX on Exchange 2016, you're going to do a lot more spam processing on your infrastructure.  If you use O365/EOP, they will cut out a significant chunk before it even reaches you.

In case I wasn't clear, you can have on-prem Exchange and still leverage Exchange Online Protection.  It's not free, however.